# spring-data-jpa-datatables: Ignore Hibernate @Where annotation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-jpa-datatables

For `spring-data-jpa-datatables:4.3`, how to make `DataTablesRepository` to return all entities, ignoring the Hibernate's `@Where` annotation?

This is an entity with Hibernate's `@Where` annotation:

```
@Entity
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE vehicle SET deleted_at = NOW() WHERE id = ?")
@Where(clause = "deleted_at IS NULL")
public class Vehicle extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable {...}
```

And this is a corresponding repository extending spring-data-jpa-datatables's `DataTablesRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface VehicleDataTableRepository extends DataTablesRepository<Vehicle, Long> {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible. The `@Where` predicate is always applied. You can map the same table again to a different entity class without the `@Where` and query that instead if you want though or you create a filter (`@Filter`) instead of using `@Where` and just ensure the filter is always active except when you explicitly don't want the filter predicate to be applied. Also see: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filter

Answer (score 0):

You can write a native query like below.

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM table Name", nativeQuery=true)
public ignoreWhereClauseQuery(){}
```

The SQL in the @Query annotation must point the table's name and the fields' names (not entity's name).

Comment: spring-data-jpa-datatables has it's own implementation of `DataTablesRepository`, I doubt that the `nativeQuery` can help here.
Please see github.com/darrachequesne/spring-data-jpa-datatables

Comment: You can create your own method and use native query for that.

Comment: Again, this is not the case. The purpose of the pring-data-jpa-datatables is to create queries dynamically under the hood, based on the GUI state.
nativeQuery contradicts the very idea.